# xml parsing and extract attribute value with xPath

Tags: python-3.x, xml, xpath, xml-parsing, lxml

I want to extract N.1.2, N.1.1, N.2.r.1, ...., N.1.3, N.1.4 with xPath

So, There are xpaths are in my dictionary.

```py
# Value - Types of Message in batch
"N.1.1": R3Item(
    elemId="N.1.1",
    xPath="/MCCI_IN200100UV01[@ITSVersion='XML_1.0'][@xsi:schemaLocation='urn:hl7-org:v3 MCCI_IN200100UV01.xsd']/name[@codeSystem='2.16.840.1.113883.3.989.2.1.1.1']/@code",
    required=True,
    comment="N.1.1 - Types of Message in batch",
),
# Types of Message in batch
"N.1.1_csv": R3Item(
    elemId="N.1.1_csv",
    xPath="/MCCI_IN200100UV01[@ITSVersion='XML_1.0'][@xsi:schemaLocation='urn:hl7-org:v3 MCCI_IN200100UV01.xsd']/name[@codeSystem='2.16.840.1.113883.3.989.2.1.1.1']/@codeSystemVersion",
    required=True,
),
# Value - Batch Number
"N.1.2": R3Item(
    elemId="N.1.2",
    xPath="/MCCI_IN200100UV01[@ITSVersion='XML_1.0'][@xsi:schemaLocation='urn:hl7-org:v3 MCCI_IN200100UV01.xsd']/id[@root='2.16.840.1.113883.3.989.2.1.3.22']/@extension",
    required=True,
    comment="N.1.2 - Batch Number",
),
# Value - Batch Sender Identifier
"N.1.3": R3Item(
    elemId="N.1.3",
    xPath="/MCCI_IN200100UV01[@ITSVersion='XML_1.0'][@xsi:schemaLocation='urn:hl7-org:v3 MCCI_IN200100UV01.xsd']/sender[@typeCode='SND']/device[@classCode='DEV'][@determinerCode='INSTANCE']/id[@root='2.16.840.1.113883.3.989.2.1.3.13'][1]/@extension",
    required=True,
    comment="N.1.3 - Batch Sender Identifier",
),
# Value - Batch Receiver Identifier
"N.1.4": R3Item(
    elemId="N.1.4",
    xPath="/MCCI_IN200100UV01[@ITSVersion='XML_1.0'][@xsi:schemaLocation='urn:hl7-org:v3 MCCI_IN200100UV01.xsd']/receiver[@typeCode='RCV']/device[@classCode='DEV'][@determinerCode='INSTANCE']/id[@root='2.16.840.1.113883.3.989.2.1.3.14'][1]/@extension",
    required=True,
    comment="N.1.4 - Batch Receiver Identifier",
),
# Value - Date of Batch Transmission
"N.1.5": R3Item(
    elemId="N.1.5",
    xPath="/MCCI_IN200100UV01[@ITSVersion='XML_1.0'][@xsi:schemaLocation='urn:hl7-org:v3 MCCI_IN200100UV01.xsd']/creationTime/@value",
    required=True,
    comment="N.1.5 - Date of Batch Transmission",
),
# Value - Message Identifier
"N.2.r.1": R3Item(
    elemId="N.2.r.1",
    xPath="//PORR_IN049016UV[r]/id[@root='2.16.840.1.113883.3.989.2.1.3.1'][1]/@extension",
    required=True,
    comment="N.2.r.1 - Message Identifier",
),
# Value - Message Sender Identifier
"N.2.r.2": R3Item(
    elemId="N.2.r.2",
    xPath="/MCCI_IN200100UV01[@ITSVersion='XML_1.0'][@xsi:schemaLocation='urn:hl7-org:v3 MCCI_IN200100UV01.xsd']/PORR_IN049016UV[r]/sender[@typeCode='SND']/device[@classCode='DEV'][@determinerCode='INSTANCE']/id[@root='2.16.840.1.113883.3.989.2.1.3.11'][1]/@extension",
    required=True,
    comment="N.2.r.2 - Message Sender Identifier",
),
# Value - Message Receiver Identifier
"N.2.r.3": R3Item(
    elemId="N.2.r.3",
    xPath="/MCCI_IN200100UV01[@ITSVersion='XML_1.0'][@xsi:schemaLocation='urn:hl7-org:v3 MCCI_IN200100UV01.xsd']/PORR_IN049016UV[r]/receiver[@typeCode='RCV']/device[@classCode='DEV'][@determinerCode='INSTANCE']/id[@root='2.16.840.1.113883.3.989.2.1.3.12'][1]/@extension",
    required=True,
    comment="N.2.r.3 - Message Receiver Identifier",
),
# Value - Date of Message Creation
"N.2.r.4": R3Item(
    elemId="N.2.r.4",
    xPath="/MCCI_IN200100UV01[@ITSVersion='XML_1.0'][@xsi:schemaLocation='urn:hl7-org:v3 MCCI_IN200100UV01.xsd']/PORR_IN049016UV[r]/creationTime/@value",
    required=True,
    comment="N.2.r.4 - Date of Message Creation",
),
```

below is the part of the sample xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MCCI_IN200100UV01 ITSVersion="XML_1.0" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:hl7-org:v3 MCCI_IN200100UV01.xsd" xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <id extension="N.1.2" root="2.16.840.1.113883.3.989.2.1.3.22"/>
    <creationTime value="N.1.5"/>
    <responseModeCode code="D"/>
    <interactionId extension="MCCI_IN200100UV01" root="2.16.840.1.113883.1.6"/>
    <name code="N.1.1" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.3.989.2.1.1.1" codeSystemVersion="1.01"/>
    <PORR_IN049016UV>
        <id extension="N.2.r.1" root="2.16.840.1.113883.3.989.2.1.3.1"/>
        <creationTime value="N.2.r.4"/>
        <interactionId extension="PORR_IN049016UV" root="2.16.840.1.113883.1.6"/>
        <processingCode code="P"/>
        <processingModeCode code="T"/>
        <acceptAckCode code="AL"/>
        <receiver typeCode="RCV">
            <device classCode="DEV" determinerCode="INSTANCE">
                <id extension="N.2.r.3" root="2.16.840.1.113883.3.989.2.1.3.12"/>
            </device>
        </receiver>
    </PORR_IN049016UV>
    <receiver typeCode="RCV">
        <device classCode="DEV" determinerCode="INSTANCE">
            <id extension="N.1.4" root="2.16.840.1.113883.3.989.2.1.3.14"/>
        </device>
    </receiver>
    <sender typeCode="SND">
        <device classCode="DEV" determinerCode="INSTANCE">
            <id extension="N.1.3" root="2.16.840.1.113883.3.989.2.1.3.13"/>
        </device>
    </sender>
</MCCI_IN200100UV01>
```

below is my code, but the result are empty lists.
I want to extract like "N.1.1"

```py
def extractData(tree):
    """r3 data extracted by xpath"""
    root = tree.getroot()
    keys = getList(R3_DATA)
    for key in keys:
        xPath = getxPath(key)
        print(root.xpath(xPath))
```

How should I fix this or what should I do?
If there is the other library or sample code to be able to do this, then could you let me know?

Comment: getvalue returns key's xpath of the dictionary

Comment: The elements are in the namespace `xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3"` so your XPath evaluation code needs to take the namespace into account.

Comment: In some older lxml versions but not the latest releases I think you could use `root.xpath(xPath, namespaces = { None : 'urn:hl7-org:v3' })`

Comment: The error (TypeError: empty namespace prefix is not supported in XPath ) is occurred. root.xpath("/MCCI_IN200100UV01[@ITSVersion='XML_1.0'][@xsi:schemaLocation='urn:hl7-org:v3 MCCI_IN200100UV01.xsd']/PORR_IN049016UV[1]/sender[@typeCode='SND']/device[@classCode='DEV'][@determinerCode='INSTANCE']/id[@root='2.16.840.1.113883.3.989.2.1.3.11'][1]/@extension",namespaces={None:'urn:hl7-org:v3', "xsi":"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"})

Comment: You could also try whether `find` or `findall` support your paths, I think these functions do support the use of a second argument `{ None : 'urn:hl7-org:v3' }` as the second argument to use a default namespace.

Comment: As I said, the use of `namespaces = { None : 'urn:hl7-org:v3' }` I think only worked with older releases. However, `find` or `findall` have a similar argument although those functions are not as flexible regarding the complete XPath syntax.

Comment: @MartinHonnen you mean that the modification from "/MCCI_IN200100UV01[@ITSVersion='XML_1.0'][@xsi:schemaLocation='urn:hl7-org:v3 MCCI_IN200100UV01.xsd']/PORR_IN049016UV[r]/creationTime/@value" to "root.findall(/MCCI_IN200100UV01/PORR_IN049016UV/creationTime)" would be better for this right?

Comment: Along those lines, I am afraid I don't know all details of the restrictions off the top of my head, I think `MCCI_IN200100UV01[@ITSVersion='XML_1.0']` would pass, I think somehow the find methods don't like absolute paths starting with `/` but want e.g. `./`. So basically adapting the path expressions to the restrictions the find methods require would be necessary. If you want to use the `xpath` method then the XPath expressions need to use a prefix (e.g. `hl7` in `/hl7:MCCI_IN200100UV01[@ITSVersion='XML_1.0']` and declare that in the second argument.

Comment: @MartinHonnen I changed all my xPath start with /MCCI_IN200100UV01 to /hl7:MCCI_IN200100UV01 and I tested               print(root.xpath(xPath, namespaces={'hl7':'urn:hl7-org:v3', 'xsi':'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'})), however the empty lists are returned

Comment: 'xsi':'w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' -->
'xsi':'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'

Comment: The namespace prefix needs to be used on all elements in each path

Comment: @MartinHonnen I tried to run my code adding hl7 in front of all tags, but it didn't work. So, now I am trying to decompose all xpath getting tag path instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted, your xpaths need the namespaces. Here's an example of how to use namespaces with lxml. Note the `u:` and `x:` prefixes in the xpath.

```
In [1]: from lxml import etree

In [2]: root = etree.parse('mcci.xml')

In [3]: NS = {'u': 'urn:hl7-org:v3', 'x': 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'}

In [4:] xpath = "/u:MCCI_IN200100UV01[@ITSVersion='XML_1.0'][@x:schemaLocation='urn:hl7-org:v3 MCCI_IN200100UV01.xsd']/u:creationTime/@value"

In [5]: root.xpath(xpath, namespaces=NS)
Out[5]: ['N.1.5']
```

I might recommend removing the predicate that involves the schema location to simplify things somewhat.

```
In [6]: NS = {'u': 'urn:hl7-org:v3'}

In [7]: xpath = "/u:MCCI_IN200100UV01[@ITSVersion='XML_1.0']/u:creationTime/@value"

In [8]: root.xpath(xpath, namespaces=NS)
Out[8]: ['N.1.5']
```